# Length of Rcpp::List differs between Windows and Mac

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am checking the length of an `Rcpp::List` object, and notice that I get different results on Windows than on Mac.

### C++ code

Here is my C++ code, in the file `"test.cpp"`. I have a `Data` class, whose constructor takes an `Rcpp::List` and extracts its element named `"constraints"`. Next, I have a function `foo` which constructs a `Data` element, extracts the length of `constraints`, and returns it.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

struct Data {
  Data(List data) :
  constraints { as<List>(data["constraints"]) } {}
  ~Data() = default;
  
  const List constraints;
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int foo(List dat) {
  Data dd {dat};
  int result = dd.constraints.length();
  return result;
}
```

### Results running in R on Mac

Here is my session:

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.2 RC (2023-10-30 r85440)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.1.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Europe/Oslo
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] vctrs_0.6.4       cli_3.6.1         knitr_1.45        rlang_1.1.2       xfun_0.41         processx_3.8.2   
 [7] purrr_1.0.2       styler_1.10.2     glue_1.6.2        clipr_0.8.0       htmltools_0.5.7   ps_1.7.5         
[13] fansi_1.0.5       rmarkdown_2.25    R.cache_0.16.0    evaluate_0.23     tibble_3.2.1      fastmap_1.1.1    
[19] yaml_2.3.7        lifecycle_1.0.4   compiler_4.3.2    fs_1.6.3          Rcpp_1.0.11.2     pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[25] rstudioapi_0.15.0 R.oo_1.25.0       R.utils_2.12.3    digest_0.6.33     R6_2.5.1          reprex_2.0.2     
[31] utf8_1.2.4        pillar_1.9.0      callr_3.7.3       magrittr_2.0.3    R.methodsS3_1.8.2 tools_4.3.2      
[37] withr_2.5.2
```

Next, I source the C++ code:

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp("test.cpp")
```

Giving `foo` a list whose `constraints` element is `NULL`, gives length zero as expected:

```r
> data <- list(a = rnorm(100), constraints = NULL, b = letters)
> foo(data)
[1] 0
```

Next, giving it a list whose `constraints` element has 26 letters, returns length 26:

```r
> data <- list(a = rnorm(100), constraints = letters, b = letters)
> foo(data)
[1] 26
```

### Results running R on Windows

I run the same R code on Windows, but obtain different results.

Here is my session info:

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] C

time zone: Europe/Oslo
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.3.2           magrittr_2.0.3           R6_2.5.1                
 [4] cli_3.6.1                tools_4.3.2              RcppArmadillo_0.12.6.6.0
 [7] rstudioapi_0.15.0        Rcpp_1.0.11.6            brio_1.1.3              
[10] testthat_3.2.0           rlang_1.1.2
```

I source the script again:

```r
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("test.cpp")
```

Here is the result when `constraints` is `NULL`. Surprisingly, it returns length 1.

```r
> data <- list(a = rnorm(100), constraints = NULL, b = letters)
> foo(data)
[1] 1
```

Here is the result when `constraints` has 26 letters. Again it returns length 1.

```r
> data <- list(a = rnorm(100), constraints = letters, b = letters)
> foo(data)
[1] 1
```

### Question

Is this expected? Am I doing something here which causes undefined behavior, and hence gives different results with different compilers/platforms?

How should I change the code to get the behavoir I want, which is that the length should be zero when it is `NULL` and nonzero otherwise?

### Updated after answer

Based on Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer below, I realize that it's best to refactor my code such that it does not contain such a deep level of nesting. In any case, I think it's worthwhile to include here that Eddelbuettel's test returns the same on Windows as on Mac:

```r
> Rcpp::cppFunction("int ll(List L) { return L.length(); }")
> ll(NULL)
[1] 0
> ll(letters)
[1] 26
```

Comment: You may be able to buiild up from this simplest access to `.length()` on a `Rcpp::List` to see when/where/how things start to differ for Windows.  There could be a bug, but it is possibly also something else as this code has seen quite a bit of use.

Comment: I suppose that `constraints { as<List>(data["constraints"]) }` probably gets parsed differently in Linux and Windows due to some compiler difference. Try changing constraints{...} to constraints(...)? The {} syntax is *usually* used to create a list of what is inside {}, in this case a list of one list.

Comment: Wow, changing from braces to parentheses solved it, @user253751. Do you want to provide it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this code:

```
constraints { as<List>(data["constraints"]) }
```

on Linux initializes `constraints` directly with `as<List>(data["constraints"])`, and on Windows initializes it as a list containing one item, which is `as<List>(data["constraints"])`.

This `{}` initialization syntax is normally used to initialize with a list of things, via `std::initializer_list`. It might not be doing that on Linux, due to a slightly different version of R, the compiler, or the compiler options.

Change `{` and `}` to `(` and `)` in this part, to force it to initialize `constraints` directly with `as<List>(data["constraints"])`.

Comment: That's a strong conjecture, and it is the same code.  Can you back out "why"?  I don't see how.  What you say about curly initializers is true is the abstract sense but practically irrelevant _as we always pass down to the C datastructure `SEXP` that it is the only interface offered by R's `.Call()`_ so my money is more on a compiler irregularity.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel What? This is a C++ question, not an R question, even though the problem occurred while interfacing with R.

Comment: Yes but it is specifically an Rcpp question. Which makes it concerned with the very R data type `SEXP` I mentioned.  So as I said, what you wrote 'works in theory' but in practice _here_ it is a little different.  Also `Rcpp::List` is not `std::list` etc.

Comment: Well I co-wrote Rcpp so consider just taking my word for it.  Rcpp, among other things, creates glue code (via a wrapper generator and some template metaprogramming) and that then interfaces R via the `.Call()` interface offered by R which _only_ takes (union type) `SEXP` variables and returns one. For Rcpp, start maybe [here](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf)  (and no harm intended, I understand where you come from but _there is more going on here_).

Comment: If you run either `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` (what OP used) or `Rcpp::cppFunction()` with the `verbose=TRUE` argument you see the generated code.  Otherwise brows source at GitHub eg in the github.com/cran organization holding 20+ thousand CRAN packages including 2700+ using Rcpp.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Indeed I notice on your website that List is a typedef of Vector, and Vector has no initializer_list constructor. Given that this is still expected behaviour of C++ container types, and it did solve the asker's problem, I presume I am just not seeing a path the compiler sees to implicitly convert from initializer_list to Vector. (It can't be Vector(T, enable_if<...>) since the enable_if condition is false.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Are you suggesting that the relevant part of C++ code is modified by Rcpp before it's compiled?

Comment: A fair amount of Rcpp code was written before brace initialization was added / became more widespread which still does not explain why the (identical, apart from versions) `g++` compiler suite treats it differently on two platforms so I still expect a simple bug somewhere.  I recommended to OP (in the answer you, likely, chose to downvote) to build initialization up from the simpler working example I showed as the Rcpp instanrtiation is not platform-dependent.  But I have no interest in shadow boxng with your here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to Windows machine but on my Linux your example *basically* seems to boil down to

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("int ll(List L) { return L.length(); }")
> ll(letters)
[1] 26
> ll(NULL)
[1] 0
>
```

Nesting multiple structures as you have done, and as we can in R, is not always possibly or advisable as the C++ code needs somewhat delicate template metaprogramming to unwind the structures.  I have found time and time again that if in doubt, trying something simpler first and building up from that helps.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.